# Referer Redirect in a POST call in symfony 4 using URL with annotations comments Routes

Tags: refresh, symfony4

In version symfony 4, I am trying to resolve a redirect in a action done  before with a parameter. I Have annotations Routes.

The problem is it is a POST call and I do not know how convert the URL $request->headers->get('referer') in a action_name or how insert the parameters in the call.

```
$op = 4; //This is an example of a number

$response = new RedirectResponse($request->headers->get('referer'),307,$headers=['op'=>$op]);
return $response;
```

or

```
$op = 4; //This is an example of a number    
$response = $this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer'));
return $response;
```

Do you know any way resolves this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject the `router` service (instance of `RouterInterface`) and use its `match` or `matchRequest` method.

Ex:

```php
public function testAction(RouterInterface $router, Request $request) {
    $route = $router->matchRequest(Request::create($request->headers->get('referer')));

    return $this->redirectToRoute($route['_route'], ['op' => 4], 307);
}
```

Comment: In the return call, I had to replace from $routeName to  $routeName['_route']